# How to use diffrenet versions of Okhttp on a project?

Tags: android, gradle, retrofit, okhttp

I am developing an android application with minSdk=17 and i'm using retrofit for server requests.
My Problem is OkHttp 3.13 Requires Android 5+ (minSdk=21).
For supporting android API levels lower than 21 i should use OkHttp 3.12.x.
I don't want to downgrade OkHttp to 3.12.x for all API levels because of security issues according to this
[article](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5-818bb78d07ce)
and I don't want to make seprate APKs, because it is just one file that works with OkHttp (My RemoteRepo) and it is easier to maintain application with just one APK.
Is it possible to make 2 modules for my server Requests one for SDK < 21 and the other for SDK >= 21?
For example i want to do something like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { 
    //use Retrofit with OkHttp 3.13
} else {
    //use Retrofit with OkHttp 3.12.x
}
```

Comment: OkHttp 3.12.x will use the same security features as newer releases on devices where it is available. So using OkHttp 3.12x everywhere is not significantly less secure than using 3.12 on old devices and 4.x on new devices.

Comment: so you suggest to use OkHttp 3.12 for all APIs in my case? @JesseWilson

Comment: Yes. 3.12.x until you can upgrade past Android 4.4.